# Pacemaker corosync 2-node with a 3rd for quorum

Tags: mysql, cluster, drbd, pacemaker, corosync

I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure a 2-node setup with a third
simpler one for quorum.

It seems to think all the nodes have the capability to act as a full fallback node, when I only I want a quorum with STONITH working sanely for what is essentially a 2+1 DRBD-MySQL node system.

Any tips or documentation on how to make the 3rd node just a quorum member would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/high_availability_add-on_reference/s1-quorumdev-haar

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 provides full support for the ability to configure a separate quorum device which acts as a third-party arbitration device for the cluster. Its primary use is to allow a cluster to sustain more node failures than standard quorum rules allow. A quorum device is recommended for clusters with an even number of nodes and highly recommended for two-node clusters.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Using Location constraints this seems quite simple (I hope). Got a bit blind sighted by an overwhelming amount of new cluster stuff.

Answer (score 0):

In mine case setting up third node and put it permanently in standby node, solved problem with migrating resources.

Comment: Could you give more details about your solution and your setup?